# CakePHP Model Extended Association

Tags: cakephp, model, model-associations

While looking at an InventoryCategory summary I can get the Inventory but not the InventoryImages.  The error reported by CakePHP is [ Model "Inventory" is not associated with model "InventoryImage" ].  These are the models I'm employing:

```
class InventoryCategory extends InventoriesAppModel {
public $hasMany = 
    array(
          'Inventory' 
        , 'InventoryCategoryImage' => array 
            (
                  'className'   => 'Media.MediaImage' 
                , 'foreignKey'  => 'foreign_key' 
                , 'conditions'  => array(
                              'InventoryCategoryImage.model' => 'InventoryCategoryImage' 
                            , 'InventoryCategoryImage.group' => 'Inventory Category Image' 
                            , 
                  )
                , 'dependent'   => true 
                , 
            ) 
        , 
    );

public function containedModels() 
{
    $contain = array(
              'Inventory' 
            , 'InventoryCategoryImage' 
            , 
    );
    return $contain;
}

}

class Inventory extends InventoriesAppModel {

public $belongsTo = 
    array(
          'User' 
        , 'InventoryCategory' 
        , 
    );

public $hasMany = 
    array(
          'InventoryImage' => array
            (
                  'className'   => 'Media.MediaImage' 
                , 'foreignKey'  => 'foreign_key' 
                , 'conditions'  => array(
                              'InventoryImage.model' => 'InventoryImage' 
                            , 'InventoryImage.group' => 'Inventory Image' 
                            , 
                  )
                , 'dependent'   => true 
                , 'order'   => 'InventoryImage.rank ASC, InventoryImage.id ASC' 
            ) 
        , 
    );

public function containedModels() 
{
    $contain = array(
              'User' 
            , 'InventoryCategory' 
            , 
    );
    return $contain;
}

}
```

Comment: Is `'recursive' => 2` in your find() call?  Also, please post the find call that gives you that error.

Comment: No.  I don't use recursive.  Contain instead.

Comment: `code`public function view() 
    {
      if( !$this->params['id'] ) 
      {
 $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
      }
      $conditions = ( is_numeric( $this->params['id'] ) ) 
         ? array( $this->modelClass . '.id = ' => $this->params['id'] ) 
         : array( $this->modelClass . '.slug = ' => $this->params['id'] );

       $item  = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find(
            'first' 
          , array(
             'conditions' => $conditions 
           , 'contain' => $this->{$this->modelClass}->containedModels()
   )
 );
        $this->set( compact( 'item' ) );
    }`code`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by declaring `$hasMany` in `InventoryCategory` you replace and erase the `$hasMany` array from its parent's class.

The `$hasMany` declaration should therefore also contain the parent's associations in order to get it to work.

A different approach would be to append new associations to the parent's `$hasMany` array.
The question here is: what callback to use. I don't know (I'm looking for an answer too). So far I think the `public function __construct()` is the most suitable.

Like this:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct();

    // adding Blog-specific Card-association.
    // Blog is a class extending some other class that does not know about the Class association.
    $this->belongsTo['Card'] = array(
        'className' => 'Card',
        'foreignKey' => 'card_id'
    );
}
```